JavaScript Parallax side scrolling not updating scroll speed for each layer
I am creating a parallax side scrolling animation, and the speed seems to be not updating for each of the layers, I created a parallax layers class where it takes an array of images and array of speed values for each of the layer, that outputs a parallax animation on a canvas, and it animates all the layers, but does not update the speed for the individual layer but instead uses the same speed value for all the layers.
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width = 1600;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height = 720;





class parralaxLayer {
    constructor(imageARR, speedARR) {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.width = 3840;
        this.height = 720;
        this.x2 = this.width;
        this.imageArray = imageARR;
        this.speedArray = speedARR;
        this.i = 0;
        this.imgSet = []
        this.speed = []
        this.gameSpeed = 5

        //puts a object of images in an array
        Object.values(this.imageArray).forEach((layer) => {
            let img = new Image()
            img.src = layer
            this.imgSet.push(img)

        })

        //loads speed values for each layer
        this.speedArray.forEach((layer) => {
            let speedVals = layer * this.gameSpeed
            this.speed.push(speedVals)

        })




    }

    updateDraw(img, speed) {
        //try a for loop or for each loop here
        if (this.x <= -this.width) {
            this.x = this.width + this.x2 - speed
        }

        if (this.x2 <= -this.width) {
            this.x2 = this.width + this.x - speed;
        }


        this.x = Math.floor(this.x - speed);
        this.x2 = Math.floor(this.x2 - speed);

        ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.drawImage(img, this.x2, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }



    //when loading indvidually speed is correct rendering it sets it to one speed
    animate() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        //draws each of the layers and images
        for (let i = 0; i < this.imgSet.length; i++) {
            let speed = this.gameSpeed * this.speedArray[i]
            this.updateDraw(this.imgSet[i], speed);

        }

        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
    }



}



let arrayofSpeed = [0.2, 0.4, 1, 2, 4]

let dayScene = new parralaxLayer(timeCollection[0], arrayofSpeed)

console.log(dayScene.speed)


dayScene.animate()

I tried putting all the function inside the class, as animate was initially outside, of the class, and also changed game speed from a global variable to the variable inside the class, and update and draw were separate method, so I combined it with it taking the speed value and image of the current parallax layer, but nothing seems to be working.

Your class code was a mixture of trying to draw all images and only drawing one image.
The speed problem was due to using the essentially the same x value for all images.
You were only offsetting the x of each image from the first image.
In your constructor, this.width should be CANVAS_WIDTH and this.height should be CANVAS_HEIGHT.
If your images are not all the same width, then you should draw them at this.img.width
See the NOTE's on specific changes in the code snippet below.


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// NOTE Changed canvas size for debugging purposes
const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width = 800; // 1600;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height = 320; // 720;


class parralaxLayer {
  constructor(imageName, speed) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    // NOTE This probably needs to be the canvas width
    this.width = CANVAS_WIDTH; // 3840;
    // NOTE This should probably be the same as the canvas height
    this.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT; // 720;
    this.x2 = this.width;
    this.gameSpeed = 3;
    this.speed = speed * this.gameSpeed;

    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = imageName;
  }


  updateDraw( ) {
    //try a for loop or for each loop here
    if (this.x <= -this.width) {
      this.x = this.width + this.x2 - this.speed;
    }

    if (this.x2 <= -this.width) {
      this.x2 = this.width + this.x - this.speed;
    }

    this.x = Math.floor(this.x - this.speed);
    this.x2 = Math.floor(this.x2 - this.speed);

    // NOTE For debug with my images, I need to draw at the image's own size
    // ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    // ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x2, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.img.width, this.img.height);
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x2, this.y, this.img.width, this.img.height);
  }
}


let timeCollection = [
  "https://www.ripspics.com/test/images/background-800x320.png",
  "https://www.ripspics.com/test/images/bush-400x320.png",
  "https://www.ripspics.com/test/images/mushroom-400x320.png",
  "https://www.ripspics.com/test/images/ground-plant-256x320.png",
  "https://www.ripspics.com/test/images/toad-140x320.png"
];

let arrayofSpeed = [0.2, 0.4, 1, 2, 3];

// NOTE A place to store all the objects we create with the parralaxLayer class
let imageObjects = [];

// NOTE Create an object for each image and store it in the new imageObjects array
for( let imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < timeCollection.length; ++imageIndex ) {
  imageObjects.push(new parralaxLayer(timeCollection[imageIndex], arrayofSpeed[imageIndex]));
}

// Start the animation 
animate();

// NOTE Moved the animation outside of the class, with appropriate edits 
function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

    //draws each of the layers and images
    for( let imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < timeCollection.length; ++imageIndex ) {
      imageObjects[imageIndex].updateDraw( );
    }

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>




You are using the same x for all the layers. I think each layer should be one image, but for simplicity I just turned the x variable into an array.


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
const CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width = 400;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height = 200;

class parralaxLayer {
  constructor(imageARR, speedARR) {
    this.x = []
    this.y = [];
    this.width = 800;
    this.height = 200;
    this.x2 = [];
    this.imageArray = imageARR;
    this.speedArray = speedARR;
    this.i = 0;
    this.imgSet = []
    this.speed = []
    this.gameSpeed = 5

    //puts a object of images in an array
    Object.values(this.imageArray).forEach((img) => {
      this.imgSet.push(img)
      this.x.push(0)
      this.y.push(0)
      this.x2.push(this.width)
    })

    //loads speed values for each layer
    this.speedArray.forEach((layer) => {
      let speedVals = layer * this.gameSpeed
      this.speed.push(speedVals)
    })
  }

  updateDraw(img, speed, i) {
    //try a for loop or for each loop here
    if (this.x[i] <= -this.width) {
      this.x[i] = this.width + this.x2[i] - speed
    }

    if (this.x2[i] <= -this.width) {
      this.x2[i] = this.width + this.x[i] - speed;
    }

    this.x[i] = Math.floor(this.x[i] - speed);
    this.x2[i] = Math.floor(this.x2[i] - speed);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.x[i], this.y[i], this.width, this.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, this.x2[i], this.y[i], this.width, this.height);
  }

  //when loading indvidually speed is correct rendering it sets it to one speed
  animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    //draws each of the layers and images
    for (let i = 0; i < this.imgSet.length; i++) {
      let speed = this.speed[i]
      this.updateDraw(this.imgSet[i], speed, i);

    }

    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
  }

}

var i = new Image()
var j = new Image()
i.onload = function() {
  let arrayofSpeed = [0.2, 0.6]

  let dayScene = new parralaxLayer([i, j], arrayofSpeed)

  dayScene.animate()
}


j.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
j.src = "https://picsum.photos/150/?id=2"

i.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
i.src = "https://picsum.photos/150"
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>



